# LINQ to SQL Compiled Queries added as a DataContext partial class does not work

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following compiled query added to my ASP.NET MVC 2 project (as a partial class definition to my LINQ to SQL DataContext):

```
namespace MyWebApp.DataAccessLayer.DataObject
{
    public partial class MyWebAppDataContext
    {
        public static Func<MyWebAppDataContext, int, IQueryable<PurchaseOrder>>
            POByID = CompiledQuery.Compile
                ((MyWebAppDataContextcontext, int poID) =>
                context.PurchaseOrders.Where(p => p.ID == poID));

        public IQueryable<PurchaseOrder> GetPObyID(int categoryID)
        {
            return POByID(this, categoryID);
        }
    }
}
```

To get PurchaseOrder list I use this code in the controller:

```
using MyWebApp.DataAccessLayer.DataObject;
...    
...
var context = new MyWebAppDataContext("...connectionstring...");
var MyPOs = context.GetPObyID(3).ToList();
```

The IntelliSense does see GetPObyID() function and VS does not see any error in the code  but I got the following compilation error:

"error CS1061: 'MyWebApp.DataAccessLayer.DataObject.MyWebAppDataContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetPObyID' and no extension method 'GetPObyID' accepting a first argument of type 'MyWebApp.DataAccessLayer.DataObject.MyWebAppDataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce your problem in VS2008.
Which tool did you use to compile your project? I guess that the cs file which includes the first section code in your question was missed during the compiling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked again the refereneces and recompiled/rebuilt all 8 projects in my solution and now it works.